# Save multiple custom fields with single update_post_meta function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a foreach loop working in the WordPress Orders & Subscription admin pages, where each repeating input is given a unique ID such as san_agreement_number_**1**, san_agreement_number_**2**, san_agreement_number_**3** etc...

There may be any number of these inputs which need to be saved on 'Update'.

I am using a function which uses the update_post_meta to save the custom field:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'sab_save_service_agreement_numbers' );
function sab_save_service_agreement_numbers( $order_id ){
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'san_agreement_number_1', wc_clean( $_POST[ 'san_agreement_number_1' ] ) );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'san_agreement_number_2', wc_clean( $_POST[ 'san_agreement_number_2' ] ) );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'san_agreement_number_3', wc_clean( $_POST[ 'san_agreement_number_3' ] ) );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'san_agreement_number_4', wc_clean( $_POST[ 'san_agreement_number_4' ] ) );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'san_agreement_number_5', wc_clean( $_POST[ 'san_agreement_number_5' ] ) );
}
```

This is obviously the wrong way to save the custom field as there might be any number of fields.

Can anyone suggest the best way to update the custom fields without having to specify each ID?

I have tried playing around with the following code, but this only saves the last custom field, not all of them. I'm not sure how to dynamically save each field in one command. Any suggestion would be most appreciated. Thank you.

```
$san_count = 1;

add_action( 'post_updated', 'sab_save_service_agreement_numbers' );
function sab_save_service_agreement_numbers( $order_id ){
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'san_agreement_number_$san_count', wc_clean( $_POST[ 'san_agreement_number_$san_count' ] ) );
    
++$san_count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterate through the `$_POST` data and update the post meta for each field

For example:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'sab_save_service_agreement_numbers' );
function sab_save_service_agreement_numbers( $order_id ){
    // Loop through the $_POST data
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        // Check if the key starts with 'san_agreement_number_'
        if( strpos( $key, 'san_agreement_number_' ) === 0 ) {
            // Get the ID number from the key
            $id = str_replace( 'san_agreement_number_', '', $key );
            // Update the post meta for this field
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'san_agreement_number_' . $id, wc_clean( $value ) );
        }
    }
}
```